# Lua parsing csv with variable number of columns without iteration

Tags: csv, lua, iteration, repeat, capture

is it possible to parse csv string that looks like this:

> DATA,063,20191001000000,aPA1: 994.39,aUBT: 12.30,bUSL: 1.50

where this part:

> DATA,063,20191001000000

is somewhat constant - DATA can be some other string and 063 some other number, but the fields are always there - and the rest can be variable number of coma separated values with format:

> label:[possible space]number

without using some kind of iteration?

I know I can use string.gmatch(line, "[^,]+") and then iterate over the result, but I'm looking for a solution that, ideally, uses one string.match() with appropriate pattern, that can split the line and save result to table so there is less function calling - to make the code faster.

I also know that captures in Lua regex don't work this way - you can't do something like string.match(line, "([^,]+)+") - ie repetition of capture, but is there any other way to do it?

Comment: So for the data `DATA,063,20191001000000,aPA1: 994.39,aUBT: 12.30,bUSL: 1.50` the sets are `DATA,063,2019blahblahblah`, `aPA1, 994.39`, `aUBT: 12.30`, `bUSL: 1.50`, however there can be any number of values after this? I'm trying to think of a pattern to write for this to use with string.gsub but 1) I can only assume using gsub isn't much faster than any other loop (I can only assume gsub uses some internal iteration) and 2) I don't know if patterns can really support unknown variable matches. It would be easier if you were certain sets would contain x to y arguments.

Comment: How many sets do you intend to iterate on and how often will you iterate? I've been doing some amateur speed tests on data not similar to yours but inspired by it and there is a speed difference. I was wrong! gsub is faster than gmatch at iterations more than a few hundred, but even at a thousand sets it is negligible.. 1/100 of a second difference, but then again I am not someone who often codes for speed with large data, so if thats important to you, you could use gsub. Here's the code I used and my results: https://pastebin.com/5KCrYc4e

Comment: Thank you, will check it out, probably tomorrow, and let you know.

Comment: I should probably mention that the code I used in the speedtest assumes a constant number of arguments in the sets, so depending on the implementation of a solution to handle variable arguments, it would change the speed and speed difference. Like I said, gsub doesn't seem well suited for variable arguments so if the speed doesn't seem awful, you could just accept the speed difference and use gmatch+match.